# RDP connection to admin account activates group policy

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, group-policy

I have a stand alone win XP sp 3 machine with two users. Admin and user.  The user has group policy activated and limited access but the admin has full access.  For some reason connecting via remote desktop to the admin account, activates the limited group policy on the admin account. Does any one know why is this happening and  How can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: Does the GPO configure Computer settings or User settings? Computer settings apply to all users that log on to the computer. If the GPO is configuring User settings are you filtering the Group Policy so that it applies only to the user and not the admin?

Comment: The GPO configures user settings. the GPO is filtered as far as I know,  but if you a suggestion on how to properly do it I would appreciate it.  The weird part is that logging to the administrator locally does not apply GPO on the admin but remotely connecting does apply it.